# How to use FLAC in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, c++, c, static-libraries

I'm developing iPhone app that should use Google Voice API, so my app should convert voice recorded in m4a to flac. Of course I should use libflac, but all my attempts to compile static library for iOS were failed due to linker errors.

So the question is:
where could I find static iOS binaries of libflac or what should I do to compile it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScummVM has libflac in their iPhone setup.  See: http://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php/Compiling_ScummVM/iPhone

I'm sure you can look over their setup to figure it out.

Comment: libflac is an external library and doesn't belong to them

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/jhurt/FLACiOS

Makes the integration of libflac into ios apps very easy...

Have fun