# Error in linking framework in ios application

Tags: iphone, architecture

Hello I am  having following error in ios project

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Documents/ios5
>   Examples/FlacPlayerUniversal/opt/iphone-4.3/lib/libFLAC++.a, missing
>   required architecture i386 in file

I have searched some post related to this error but my issue is not resolved . This error is coming when I am building project for iphone simulator  and for device, it is not giving error.

I checked framework header path , header search path .Don't know how to solve this

Please help

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Do you have access to the sources or did you simply download the `libFLAC++.a` from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You've already built (or installed) `libFLAC` for the iPhone device.

You simply need to build `libFLAC` for simulator as well.

[This question may tell you how to build for i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342099/building-libflac-on-osx-with-i386-arch-not-x86-64), but I think it's for MacOS and not iPhone simulator.  You'll need to make some tweaks to the CONFIG file.  [Here is another previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796375/how-to-use-flac-in-iphone-application) which might have useful hints, it seems to point to a wiki for an open source app that uses `libFLAC`.